# Any ASP.NET host that uses EC2?

Tags: hosting, asp.net, amazon-ec2

Is there an ASP.NET web host that operates using EC2?

I'd like to take advantage of some of the same-region perks Amazon offers like no transfer fees with S3, reduced latency via local routing with some database offerings hosted by AWS (like MongoHQ).

I've got my my ASP.NET MVC app working for what I want to do, but I'd really prefer not managing a Windows Server image myself in EC2 if there's already a hosting company out there that can do it better than me.

So, anyone know of such a ASP.NET web hosting company that abstracts out their hosting packages from Windows Server on EC2?

Comment: I doubt it, it is much more cost effective to buy your own servers and resell VMs on that hardware, than to rent from Amazon and then re-rent those VMs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered Microsoft's Azure Platform?  They have an [introductory special](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/offers/popup/popup.aspx?lang=en&locale=en-US&offer=MS-AZR-0001P) right now that may work for your requirements.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like [AppHarbor](http://appharbor.com/) is going to be '[Heroku](http://heroku.com/) for ASP.NET'.  They do ASP.NET and database hosting on Amazon's EC2 platform.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm confused, but why don't you just setup EC2 hosting yourself?  I know you said you don't want to maintain your own images, but there are images setup already that you can use.  It isn't much work to setup a server, stick the site in IIS and be done with it.